# How to change right-to-left property of a sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a new sheet using the javascript api.
In some cases this sheet needs to be right-to-left.

I know how to make it right-to-left manually, but cannot find how to do it programatically.

The code that creates the speardsheet is simple:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet("My new sheet");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, really I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the right-to-left options for sheets and cells are not exposed in Apps Script. Please [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request%20from%20user) for this capability so we can track progress on it.

Comment: Looks like I cannot submit an issue. I see "Issue attachment storage quota exceeded."

Comment: We just upped our attachment quota, please try again.

Comment: Still cannot submit it. When I hit "Submit issue" nothing happens.

Comment: Are you trying to upload a large attachment? Can you file an issue without it?

Comment: No, I'm trying to upload nothing.

Comment: The "Submit Issue" button is grey and I can do nothing to submit it.

Comment: Actually it's the same for other projects as well. Weird :(

Comment: Please verify that you are logged into your Google Account.